# Merge oracle line

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following line in my select

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
=========================
A       B      C1     X1
A       B      C2     X2
AA      BB     C3     Y1
AA      BB     C4     Y1
```

I would like

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF
=======================================
A       B      C1     X1     C2     X2
AA      BB     C3     Y1     C4     Y1
```

I try with a PIVOT but I always get a error.. I have a undefinded value of ColE and ColF but I know for a specif ColA and B I will always get 2 lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` if it is ok for you using the trick of `row_number`,

```
select *
from
(
select colA,colB,colC,colD
      ,row_number() over (partition by colA,colB order by colA,colB) rn
  from data
)
pivot
(
 max(ColC) as colC,max(ColD) as colD
 for rn in (1 as colE,2 as colF)
);
```

P.S. You can name the alias you want at the end. I have only used row number 1 and 2 as per your example case but you can mention (`hard code`) as many as you want which is the disadvantage of `pivot`. To overcome this you may need dynamic SQL as next step.

[Db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68241d886f2caa1d3e70f1d722ccd380)

Comment: Which result you mean because with your example and fiddle i provided have no null values ? could you provide db<>fiddle so that I can have a look ?